cloned elastic beanstalk environment error
I try to clone my beanstalk enviroment.before i clone the enviroment my website working but after the clone process my website become blank .I use beanstalk for my API.
I try to swap the environment but no change at all.I want to ask what i do wrong or what to do to make my website working again or what setting do i have to do to make it work again.
the clone success i try to swap the environment domain but now working after that i try return to original environment domain but still not working

log from eb-engine.log
    2024/08/30 14:03:29.922767 [INFO] Starting...
2024/08/30 14:03:29.922809 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2024/08/30 14:03:29.922844 [INFO] reading event message file
2024/08/30 14:03:29.923865 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2024/08/30 14:03:29.987095 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:03:30.229529 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:03:30.457493 [INFO] checking whether command bundle-log is applicable to this instance...
2024/08/30 14:03:30.457506 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2024/08/30 14:03:30.457518 [INFO] Engine command: (bundle-log)

2024/08/30 14:03:30.460067 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetBundleLogs
2024/08/30 14:03:30.460074 [INFO] Bundle Logs...
2024/08/30 14:03:30.682307 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2024/08/30 14:03:30.682372 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1725026610682,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2024/08/30 14:03:30.682485 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: bundle-log

2024/08/30 14:04:13.858943 [INFO] Starting...
2024/08/30 14:04:13.858977 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2024/08/30 14:04:13.858992 [INFO] reading event message file
2024/08/30 14:04:13.859142 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2024/08/30 14:04:13.921630 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:04:14.153251 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:04:14.374739 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2024/08/30 14:04:14.374750 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2024/08/30 14:04:14.374753 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2024/08/30 14:04:14.374808 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2024/08/30 14:04:14.374811 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2024/08/30 14:04:14.378003 [INFO] Running command: tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log
2024/08/30 14:04:14.381579 [INFO] Running command: tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-hooks.log
2024/08/30 14:04:14.474098 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2024/08/30 14:04:14.474160 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1725026654474,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2024/08/30 14:04:14.474272 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: tail-log

2024/08/30 14:06:59.881953 [INFO] Starting...
2024/08/30 14:06:59.881990 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2024/08/30 14:06:59.882007 [INFO] reading event message file
2024/08/30 14:06:59.882335 [INFO] Engine received EB command userdata-exec

2024/08/30 14:06:59.901854 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:07:00.118085 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374801 [INFO] Unable to ping launch url, this is a scale-up instance.
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374894 [INFO] Engine command: (self-startup)

2024/08/30 14:07:00.374900 [INFO] Downloading EB Application...
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374902 [INFO] Region: ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374905 [INFO] envID: e-dnrbcsyyub
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374908 [INFO] envBucket: elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-543596189058
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374911 [INFO] Using manifest file name from command request
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374919 [INFO] Unable to get version manifest file.
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374922 [INFO] Downloading latest manifest available.
2024/08/30 14:07:00.374924 [INFO] Download latest app version manifest
2024/08/30 14:07:00.375024 [INFO] resources/environments/e-dnrbcsyyub/_runtime/versions/manifest
2024/08/30 14:07:00.417494 [INFO] latestManifest key *: resources/environments/e-dnrbcsyyub/_runtime/versions/manifest_1725012588934

2024/08/30 14:07:00.417652 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-543596189058, object: /resources/environments/e-dnrbcsyyub/_runtime/versions/manifest_1725012588934
2024/08/30 14:07:00.435144 [INFO] Download successful140bytes downloaded
2024/08/30 14:07:00.435291 [INFO] Trying to read and parse version manifest...
2024/08/30 14:07:00.437987 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-543596189058, object: /resources/environments/e-dnrbcsyyub/_runtime/_versions/api/app-220915_222404386191
2024/08/30 14:07:01.793898 [INFO] Download successful133448007bytes downloaded
2024/08/30 14:07:01.794090 [INFO] Executing instruction: SyncClock
2024/08/30 14:07:01.794094 [INFO] Starting SyncClock
2024/08/30 14:07:01.794102 [INFO] Running command: /usr/bin/chronyc tracking
2024/08/30 14:07:01.813064 [INFO] Reference ID    : A9FEA97B (169.254.169.123)
Stratum         : 4
Ref time (UTC)  : Fri Aug 30 14:06:44 2024
System time     : 0.000001138 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000649 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000002280 seconds
Frequency       : 7.467 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.062 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000428830 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000267082 seconds
Update interval : 16.2 seconds
Leap status     : Normal

2024/08/30 14:07:01.813088 [INFO] Running command: /usr/bin/chronyc -a makestep
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815588 [INFO] 200 OK

2024/08/30 14:07:01.815611 [INFO] Skipping Configure OS
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815615 [INFO] Skipping LockRepo
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815619 [INFO] Skipping GenerateEBBanner
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815623 [INFO] Skipping Install Process Manager
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815628 [INFO] Skipping install syslog
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815631 [INFO] Skipping install cron
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815635 [INFO] Skipping install proxy
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815639 [INFO] Skipping installhealthd
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815645 [INFO] Skipping Install Log Streaming Manager
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815649 [INFO] Skipping install X-Ray
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815653 [INFO] Skipping install Third Party License
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815657 [INFO] Skipping install httpd
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815662 [INFO] Skipping installSqsd
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815668 [INFO] Skipping bootstraphealthd
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815671 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetSetupProxyLog
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815821 [INFO] Skipping Install yum packages
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815828 [INFO] Skipping Install default nodejs
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815834 [INFO] Skipping MarkBaked
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815839 [INFO] Skipping TuneSystemSettings
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815843 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetSetupLogRotate
2024/08/30 14:07:01.815845 [INFO] Initialize LogRotate files and directories
2024/08/30 14:07:01.831782 [INFO] Skipping BootstrapCFNHup
2024/08/30 14:07:01.831794 [INFO] Executing instruction: StartCFNHup
2024/08/30 14:07:01.831797 [INFO] Start cfn-hup
2024/08/30 14:07:01.831828 [INFO] Running command: systemctl show -p PartOf cfn-hup.service
2024/08/30 14:07:01.837779 [INFO] Running command: systemctl is-active cfn-hup.service
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840669 [INFO] cfn-hup process is already registered and up running, skip installation
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840687 [INFO] Skipping SetupPublishLogCronjob
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840691 [INFO] Skipping MarkBootstrapped
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840694 [INFO] Executing instruction: Save CFN Stack Info
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840796 [INFO] Executing instruction: stopSqsd
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840800 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip stop sqsd daemon ...
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840803 [INFO] Executing instruction: PreBuildEbExtension
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840806 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild.
2024/08/30 14:07:01.840815 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2024/08/30 14:07:12.891995 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild.

2024/08/30 14:07:12.893033 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2024/08/30 14:07:16.009591 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2024/08/30 14:07:16.009619 [INFO] Running command: /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2024/08/30 14:07:22.528193 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2024/08/30 14:07:23.336446 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2024/08/30 14:07:23.336475 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
2024/08/30 14:07:23.336501 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist
2024/08/30 14:07:23.336504 [INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/staging/.platform/hooks/prebuild
2024/08/30 14:07:23.336511 [INFO] Executing instruction: Install customer specified node.js version
2024/08/30 14:07:23.337650 [INFO] installing specified nodejs version...
2024/08/30 14:07:23.339548 [INFO] Running command: uname -m
2024/08/30 14:07:23.364042 [INFO] x86_64

2024/08/30 14:07:23.366779 [INFO] Running command: uname -m
2024/08/30 14:07:23.368112 [INFO] x86_64

2024/08/30 14:07:23.368745 [INFO] installing node version 14.21.3
2024/08/30 14:07:23.369626 [INFO] Running command: uname -m
2024/08/30 14:07:23.370820 [INFO] x86_64

2024/08/30 14:07:23.370829 [INFO] Downloading file with path: /tmp/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.gz
2024/08/30 14:07:23.371934 [INFO] URL: https://elasticbeanstalk-platform-assets-ap-southeast-1.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/stalks/eb_nodejs14_amazon_linux_2_1.0.3321.0_20240814212448/lib/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.gz
2024/08/30 14:07:23.734409 [INFO] Finished download file from https://elasticbeanstalk-platform-assets-ap-southeast-1.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/stalks/eb_nodejs14_amazon_linux_2_1.0.3321.0_20240814212448/lib/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.gz
2024/08/30 14:07:23.734477 [INFO] extracting /tmp/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.gz to /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install
2024/08/30 14:07:23.734487 [INFO] Running command: /usr/bin/tar -xzf /tmp/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install
2024/08/30 14:07:24.840817 [INFO] finished extracting /tmp/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.gz to /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install successfully
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845352 [INFO] create soft link from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64/bin/node to /usr/bin/node
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845411 [INFO] create soft link from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64/bin/corepack to /usr/bin/corepack
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845446 [INFO] create soft link from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64/bin/npx to /usr/bin/npx
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845482 [INFO] create soft link from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64/bin/npm to /usr/bin/npm
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845494 [INFO] Executing instruction: Use NPM to install dependencies
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845502 [INFO] found node modules dependencies, skip installing dependencies
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845505 [INFO] Executing instruction: check Procfile
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845508 [INFO] checking Procfile
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845514 [INFO] no Procfile found, generating Procfile
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845517 [INFO] checking package.json file
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845522 [INFO] found package.json file, using npm to start application
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845617 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure X-Ray
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845622 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2024/08/30 14:07:24.845625 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure proxy server
2024/08/30 14:07:24.873044 [WARN] skipping nginx folder under .ebextensions
2024/08/30 14:07:24.873071 [INFO] Running command: cp -rp /var/app/staging/.platform/nginx/. /var/proxy/staging/nginx
2024/08/30 14:07:24.889139 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure healthd specific proxy conf
2024/08/30 14:07:24.891020 [INFO] Running command: systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:24.943473 [WARN] Warning: process healthd is already registered...
Deregistering the process ...
2024/08/30 14:07:24.943496 [INFO] Running command: systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:24.947032 [INFO] Running command: systemctl is-active healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:24.949731 [INFO] Running command: systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:24.952755 [INFO] Running command: systemctl stop healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:24.975311 [INFO] Running command: systemctl disable healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:25.280154 [INFO] Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/healthd.service.

2024/08/30 14:07:25.280232 [INFO] Running command: systemctl daemon-reload
2024/08/30 14:07:25.353513 [INFO] Running command: systemctl reset-failed
2024/08/30 14:07:25.359317 [INFO] Running command: systemctl daemon-reload
2024/08/30 14:07:25.417794 [INFO] Running command: systemctl reset-failed
2024/08/30 14:07:25.420969 [INFO] Running command: systemctl is-enabled aws-eb.target
2024/08/30 14:07:25.423696 [INFO] Running command: systemctl enable aws-eb.target
2024/08/30 14:07:25.481352 [INFO] Running command: systemctl start aws-eb.target
2024/08/30 14:07:25.484914 [INFO] Running command: systemctl enable healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:25.553082 [INFO] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/healthd.service to /etc/systemd/system/healthd.service.

2024/08/30 14:07:25.553128 [INFO] Running command: systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:25.557060 [INFO] Running command: systemctl is-active healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:25.559727 [INFO] Running command: systemctl start healthd.service
2024/08/30 14:07:25.577796 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_logformat.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/healthd_logformat.conf
2024/08/30 14:07:25.580123 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_nginx.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf
2024/08/30 14:07:25.581969 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
2024/08/30 14:07:25.581979 [INFO] start to get cloudwatch log client
2024/08/30 14:07:25.582089 [INFO] start to config log streaming
2024/08/30 14:07:25.582098 [INFO] start to configure log streaming config file
2024/08/30 14:07:25.583071 [INFO] start to create cloudwatch log stream
2024/08/30 14:07:25.583077 [INFO] start to create log streaming
2024/08/30 14:07:25.606649 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/eb-engine.log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.631862 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/eb-hooks.log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.654073 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/web.stdout.log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.680048 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/nginx/error.log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.703038 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/nginx/access.log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.726017 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/httpd/access_log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.763618 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/api-env/var/log/httpd/error_log already exists. No need to create it.
2024/08/30 14:07:25.763632 [INFO] start to fetch config
2024/08/30 14:07:25.763640 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/beanstalk.json -s
2024/08/30 14:07:27.336386 [INFO] ****** processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent ******
I! Trying to detect region from ec2 D! [EC2] Found active network interface I! imds retry client will retry 1 timesSuccessfully fetched the config and saved in /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_beanstalk.json.tmp
Start configuration validation...
I! Detecting run_as_user...
I! Trying to detect region from ec2
D! [EC2] Found active network interface
I! imds retry client will retry 1 times
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent -schematest -config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
Configuration validation second phase succeeded
Configuration validation succeeded

2024/08/30 14:07:27.336396 [INFO] 2024/08/30 14:07:26 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_beanstalk.json.tmp ...
2024/08/30 14:07:26 I! Valid Json input schema.
2024/08/30 14:07:26 Configuration validation first phase succeeded

2024/08/30 14:07:27.336402 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetToggleForceRotate
2024/08/30 14:07:27.336406 [INFO] Checking if logs need forced rotation
2024/08/30 14:07:27.336418 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:07:28.055832 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 14:07:28.310567 [INFO] Generating rsyslog config from Procfile
2024/08/30 14:07:28.313202 [INFO] Running command: systemctl restart rsyslog.service
2024/08/30 14:07:28.345792 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
2024/08/30 14:07:28.345814 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
2024/08/30 14:07:28.345827 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024/08/30 14:07:29.696199 [INFO] Error occurred during build: Command 10_downloadepel failed

2024/08/30 14:07:29.696233 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: Container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details. 

2024/08/30 14:07:29.696240 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2024/08/30 14:07:29.698500 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: self-startup

2024/08/30 15:07:30.322850 [INFO] Starting...
2024/08/30 15:07:30.322886 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2024/08/30 15:07:30.322909 [INFO] reading event message file
2024/08/30 15:07:30.323255 [INFO] Engine received EB command userdata-exec

2024/08/30 15:07:30.331107 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 15:07:30.564132 [INFO] Running command: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:543596189058:stack/awseb-e-dnrbcsyyub-stack/a7e84f80-89d2-11ec-b97e-063606232f80 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-southeast-1
2024/08/30 15:07:30.814472 [INFO] Unable to ping launch url, this is a scale-up instance.
2024/08/30 15:07:30.814569 [INFO] Engine command: (self-startup)

cfn-init.log
2024-08-31 17:21:15,152 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_api
2024-08-31 17:21:16,461 [ERROR] Command 10_downloadepel (sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/) failed
2024-08-31 17:21:16,461 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_api: Command 10_downloadepel failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 10_downloadepel failed
2024-08-31 17:21:16,465 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2024-08-31 17:21:16,466 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 10_downloadepel failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 10_downloadepel failed

error  50_getcert
2024-09-03 06:53:21,178 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:21,182 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:21,186 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_api
2024-09-03 06:53:25,287 [INFO] Command 10_downloadepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:25,571 [INFO] Command 20_installepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:26,999 [INFO] Command 30_enableepl succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:42,080 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2024-09-03 06:53:42,091 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:42,093 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2024-09-03 06:53:42,096 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_api
2024-09-03 06:53:46,033 [INFO] Command 10_downloadepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:46,176 [INFO] Command 20_installepel succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:46,825 [INFO] Command 30_enableepl succeeded
2024-09-03 06:53:55,423 [INFO] Command 40_installcertbot succeeded
2024-09-03 06:54:00,545 [INFO] Command 40_installcertbot succeeded
2024-09-03 06:54:00,847 [ERROR] Command 50_getcert (sudo certbot certonly --debug --non-interactive --email no-reply@myemail.com --agree-tos --standalone --domains mydomain.com --keep-until-expiring --pre-hook "sudo service nginx stop" --post-hook "sudo service nginx start") failed
2024-09-03 06:54:00,847 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_api: Command 50_getcert failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 50_getcert failed
2024-09-03 06:54:00,851 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2024-09-03 06:54:00,851 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 50_getcert failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 278, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 50_getcert failed

ssl config .ebextension
    container_commands:
   10_downloadepel: 
    command: "sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/"
  20_installepel: 
    command: "sudo rpm -Uvh archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-*.rpm --force"
  30_enableepl: 
    command: "sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel*"
  40_installcertbot: 
    command: "sudo yum install -y certbot"
  50_getcert: 
    command: "sudo certbot certonly --debug --non-interactive --email no-reply@myemail.com --agree-tos --standalone --domains mydomain.com --keep-until-expiring --pre-hook \"sudo service nginx stop\" --post-hook \"sudo service nginx start\""
  60_link: 
    command: "ln -sf /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebcert"


can you share what is showing in application logs

@nabinsademba all the logs?

`2024/08/30 14:07:29.696199 [INFO] Error occurred during build: Command 10_downloadepel failed
2024/08/30 14:07:29.696233 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: Container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
now can you share your/var/log/cfn-init.logfrom cloud fomration log and check for10_downloadepel` .maybe you have added a hook to platform or ebextensions please check that

@0xn0b174 i add the cfn-init.log

i think this url https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/ in wget command in post build script is resulting in 404 can you replace it with working url  ?? in your post build script

@0xn0b174 where is post build script ? it is on the code or aws console?

if you have setup in code it should be there , if you havent then you need to check cloudfomration template for that elastic beanstalk

@0xn0b174 i change the link but another error for 50_getcert

why are you implemetning lets encrypt in your elasticbeanstalk, you can use a loadbalacner and use acm can you remove that

@0xn0b174 how to do that?

@0xn0b174 it is not going to work without using load balancer?

no no use loadbalancer, just remove letsecnrypt from your deployment hook, or please chekc the log file here sudo cat /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log if you have access to the instance

@0xn0b174 there is an error on /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log says " 2024-09-03 06:54:01,554:ERROR:certbot.compat.misc:Error output from post-hook command sudo:
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start nginx.service"

@0xn0b174 then what should i change on the code? sorry for asking too much ,i am just handed this project ,i am not the one who made it from start

is your domain name mydomain.com, if not change it to your domain that is running in the eb

no on my code the name of my domainn not mydomain.com just for the question

did you add the ip of new ec2 in easlstic beanstalk to your dns of yoru domain , i mean in the A record of your DNS

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@0xn0b174 i didnt change anything ,how to change that?

#1 Did you find the cause of the error? #2 Is the error in the clone right? #3 As others said you, try to deploy only your  application, not cert or other things #3 Deploy in another environment just your application and the clone it. Share the results. #4 In your logs, several steps failed: 10_downloadepel, 50_getcert #5 In a fresh environment, execute the step: 50_getcert and share the results. We need the log of the error to help you. Aws logs are not helping us

@JRichardsz problem solve the app uploaded to elastic beanstalk but now error (111: Connection refused) here the detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78955479/elastic-beanstalk-error-failed-111-connection-refused

What was the error? Post it as answer
