Elastic Beanstalk error failed (111: Connection refused)
I use Elastic Beanstalk for my API. I just uploaded a new version of the app, and the upload was successful. However, the API is not loading. Could you please help me resolve this issue? I am new to AWS, so I would appreciate a step-by-step guide on how to address it. I’m not sure where to look.
Here is the error message from error.log
 2024/09/06 02:27:28 [error] 29739#29739: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.97.73.245, server: localhost, request: "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm", host: "18.139.55.145:443"

here the code for https_custom.config
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 256;
}

# HTTP server
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
    include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/he*.conf;
    client_max_body_size    25M;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       443 default ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    error_page 497 https://$host$request_uri;
    client_max_body_size    25M;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    
    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebcert/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/ebcert/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location ~ ^/(lib/|img/) {
        root /var/app/current/public;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection      "Upgrade";
    }
}


ssh into your ec2 where your eb app is hosted and make sure your node app is running, as per the error it must be down to some reason, please confirm that node js is running in port 3000
